Find minimum values for unique values found in a column in Excel
I have an excel sheet set up like this:

I want a formula to find the minimum value for each Run number, what is the easiest way to do this? The run number is an auto-calculated column based on other fields in the excel sheet, in case that makes it slightly more complicated.
The amount of time values for each run changes as each run does not have the same amount of time values. I then plan to use this minimum value to calculate the delta for each row based on run number

MINIFS should work.

Do you have a GROUPBY(), then can produce a concise report: =GROUPBY(B2:B15,A2:A15,MIN,,0) or else use MINIFS() as mentioned by @BigBen Sir: =LET(a,B2:B15,b,UNIQUE(a),HSTACK(b,MINIFS(A2:A15,a,b)))

First, thank you for trying to help. When I do the MINIFS statement, it returns "#VALUE", could this be due to the columns I am referring to for the min value being a Merged Column? The formula I wrote is: =MINIFS(D13:E262,BQ13:BQ539, 1)

Please create a [reprex]. Also your ranges contain differing number of rows. What's the 1 supposed to be?

Hmm possible. But why is it merged? Dont use merged cells, its like killer you see, even you faced just now!

Unfortunately, it is not a report I created so the merged columns are there. I found that to be the issue. I also put the 1 in there just for the time being to make sure it worked for Run 1 before I put in the column referencing the run number. I think I found a workaround where I create a hidden column that equals the values in the merged columns. Thank you all for the help it is greatly appreciated!

your minifs fails because the ranges are different size.  The value is in the upper left cell in the merged range try: =MINIFS(D13:D539,BQ13:BQ539, 1)
